# Capture XMX value from all Java process running on server in single unit

Tags: bash, shell

We have process running under a user drack. we want to understand the total memory being used by the user at a specific time in single unit say in GBs or MBs.

Initially I am using this , challenge is I am copping last value which represents G or M like from `4096M 10240M 4720G`

```
$ var1=`ps -ef|grep -i drack| egrep -vi "grep|bash"| egrep -o '|Xmx[0-9]*' |tr '\r' ' '`
$ echo $var1
Xmx4096
$ var2=`echo $var1 | sed 's/^...//'`
$ echo $var2
4096
$
```

and then capture for all , below is the logic I was recommended.

```
pgrep -f 'java.*drack' | xargs ps -ocmd -p | sed -n 's/.*-Xmx\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' | awk '{t+=$0}END{print t}'
```

Here the challenge is from `4096M 10240M 4720G` in response I see `19056`. Which is not correct as you see the units are different.

Can there be a way I can get the response as `4734336M 4734.336G` which is from calculation of `4720000 + 10240 + 4096  = 4734336M`

`4.096 + 10.24 + 4720 = 4734.336G`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand what you want.

To get list of `java` process with their -Xms values:

```
 pgrep -afU $(id -u drack) java | awk 'match($0,/-Xmx([^ ]+)/ ,a){print a[1]}'
```

This will list the max allotted memory for the each `java` process, but not the actual memory consumed by each `java` process.

#### To get the current memory consumed by user `drack`

There is a better utility specilized in reporting actual memory usage with many filters called `smem`.

Read more about `smem` [here](https://www.tecmint.com/smem-linux-memory-usage-per-process-per-user/).

Using `smem` to find actual memory consumed by user `drack`

```
smem -ku drack
```

Using `smem` to find actual `java` memory consumed by user `drack`

```
smem -ku drack -P java
```

To get only the effective memory consumed by user `drack`

```
smem -Hku cfrm | awk '{print $5}'
```

Or

```
smem -Hu cfrm -P java | awk '{print $5}'
```

Comment: Thank u for your response , sry I should have been more clear or eng isn't my 1st lang. Lemme try to explain.

Say I have three processes running under user `drack` , which has `xmx` value set as `4096M 10240M 4720G` respectively. 

I want to calculate the total Memory set already for the `drack` which will be `4734336M` OR `4734.336G`. 

here the challenge is when the `xmx` value are in different units. 

hope I am clear now.